# Can't connect to wired or wireless internet - Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: networking, wireless, lan, wired

Ubuntu newbie. I have a dual boot with Windows 10, wired/wifi working fine on Windows.

On Ubuntu, my computer is connected to the network but not connecting to the internet, I've tried with various networks. Wifi issue has been present for a while I've only just tried with wired connection and I can't suggest what changes might have created the issue.

Outputs from ip route, if config and ip addr are shown below. I hope these are helpful and thanks for any advice.

```
ip route show
default via 10.97.16.1 dev wlp1s0 
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s20u2 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 10.97.16.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.97.16.0/20 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.97.31.163 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20u2 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20u2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.87 metric 100

ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enx0023555c2668: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:55:5c:26:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:51:4f:b8:79:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.97.31.163/20 brd 10.97.31.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 10119sec preferred_lft 10119sec
    inet6 fe80::89ff:fbb5:9ca5:8b18/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s20u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:db:a7:45:25:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.87/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s20u2
       valid_lft 2585sec preferred_lft 2585sec
    inet6 fe80::c0ff:bc75:60c0:c87b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ifconfig -a
enp0s20u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.87  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::c0ff:bc75:60c0:c87b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:db:a7:45:25:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11218  bytes 10358703 (10.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3119  bytes 388796 (388.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx0023555c2668: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:23:55:5c:26:68  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 22436  bytes 1879167 (1.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22436  bytes 1879167 (1.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.97.31.163  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.97.31.255
        inet6 fe80::89ff:fbb5:9ca5:8b18  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5c:51:4f:b8:79:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10609  bytes 9421757 (9.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2734  bytes 276606 (276.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
'''
```

Comment: Any advice out there?